# How create Console Log on Asp.Net Vb

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

I want to implement a console log in my application process.

**Example:**

When the client presses the button **File Verification** the button triggers the event, in the `event RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded`

```
Public Sub RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(sender As Object, e As FileUploadedEventArgs)
    ListView.Items.add("Verification File Process Begin...") /* Show Message Immediately */
    verifyFile(file)
    If File.isValid Then
        ListView.Items.add("The File is Valid") /* Show Message Immediately */
    Else
        ListView.Items.add("The File is Invalid") /* Show Message Immediately */
    End If
    If File.size > limit Then
        ListView.Items.add("The Size File is Valid") /* Show Message Immediately */
    Else
        ListView.Items.add("The size File is Invalid") /* Show Message Immediately */
    End If
End Sub
```

I want show the messages in real time in a panel or listbox whatever

```
step 1: Verification File Process Begin...
result: The File is Valid
step 2: Verification size of file
result: The Size File is Valid
....
....
step n: Verification File Process End
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I updated your code to fix some spelling mistakes

Comment: I will not post this as an answer because its probably not the "correct" solution, but can you just have your asp.net application write out to a text file somewhere, and have a separate application check for updates periodically and refresh?  Kind of ghetto, but could function as a log.

Comment: thank you, but what I want is for the user to see the process that is taking place in real time, I mean it as something to tell you right now I'm checking the file, now I'm checking "X" thing, I'm keeping the information , something that is visual for the person who is using the application.

Comment: Are these long running steps? Can you put them into a background worker started from your uploaded event and add the messages to a Queue object within the Session and have a client-side script (ajax maybe?) in a progress page make repeated calls to get the messages from the queue and display them?